# WiFi адаптер и Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, роутер

Использую Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Есть необходимость в использовании WiFi адаптера, дабы избавиться от витой пары. Предпочтительно, чтобы адаптер поддерживал 5Гц сеть.
Поиск дал понять, что без приседаний не настроить. Спеки девайса в основном говорят о поддерживании win, mac.
Какую модель выбрать? Какая модель у вас?

Дано:

- ОС: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Провайдер: МГТС (GPON)
- Цель использования: удаленная работа (удаленный рабочий стол)
- Дистанция от WiFi роутера: 15 метров и 2 стены.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот ссылка на совместимое оборудование Wifi:
https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search&typeid=net%2Fwireless#list

В базе на данный момент 1339 устройств. Есть фильтр по вендорам. Смотрите что есть в наличии магазинов, потом ищите каждый в этом списке.